# how do i grab the classname of a clicked element and put it in a function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list items that contain a bunch of elements. I want to manipulate one of the sibling's visibility on click. But it has to be the sibling element not anything else. 
This is the JS code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$(function() {
  $('.circle').click(function(this) {
  var bro = siblings.('.content');
  var $content = ('.content');
  if(this.bro.css('visibility' , 'hidden')){
    this.css('visibility' , 'visible')
  } else {
    $content.css('visibility' , 'hidden')
   };
 });
});
```

And the markup looks something like this:

```
<li>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Content details go here</p>
 </div>
 <div id="operationsmile" class="circle"></div>
    <h1 class="date">OCTOBER</h1>
 <div class="line"></div>
</li>
```

Any help with the JS would be great. Thanks.

Comment: have you checked for any error shown in browser console?? I am not much familiar with jquery, but I think `siblings.('.content')` should be changed to something like - `$('.content').siblings()`

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I think what you need is just  `$(".circle").click(function(){ $(this).siblings('.content').toggle(); });`

Comment: Yes i have. the siblings is fine because i am just specifying which sibling exactly. But the console error is "Unaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this". It points to line 2 in the js file $('.circle') part

Comment: replace the `this` on second line with some other, `obj` or `el` or just leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it too complex, I think what you need is a `toggle` function

```
$(function () {
    $('.circle').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.content').toggle();
    });
});
```

Fiddle demo- http://jsfiddle.net/pucep658/

Also, if you want to do it as per your code. It should be

```
$(function () {
    $('.circle').click(function () {
        var divToToggle = $(this).siblings('.content');
        if (divToToggle.css('visibility') == 'visible')
             divToToggle.css('visibility', 'hidden');                                            
        else 
            divToToggle.css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```

Demo- http://jsfiddle.net/pucep658/2/

Comment: this works but i use visibility to keep its place in the DOM. toggle removes it and therefore ruins the page

Comment: @OmarElbanna : updated the answer to correct your code as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the following sibling (which is your div):

```
$(".circle").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```